# How to Ignore robots.txt file in express-session?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session

I have a Node.js project. This project use local-auth with `passport.js`, `express-session` and `connect-mongo` package to store sessions in MongoDB `sessions` collection.

Each time when I update page or moving to another page, to `sessions` collection inserted 6 new items. Thus, across some time `sessions` collection becomes very large.

Code snippet for use `express-session` and `connect-mongo`:

```
var session = require('express-session')
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
app.use(session({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: secret.secretKey,
    store: new MongoStore({
        url: secret.database,
        autoReconnect: true
    })
}))
```

Morgan output in console (this happens for each page and page update):

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project>node server.js
Node.js listening on port 3000
GET / 200 37.946 ms - 2670
GET /robots.txt 400 23.490 ms - 2328
GET /robots.txt 400 185.459 ms - 2328
GET /robots.txt 400 4.794 ms - 2328
GET /robots.txt 400 6.684 ms - 2328
GET /robots.txt 400 3.966 ms - 2328
GET /favicon.ico 400 7.314 ms - 2328
GET /robots.txt 400 3.713 ms - 2328
```

So, I think this happens by reason of many requests to `robots.txt` file.

How can I make this file ignored in `express-session` or `connect-mongo`?

Comment: You want `saveUninitialized:false`

Comment: @BrahmaDev that's not solve my problem

Comment: You mean it's still creating new sessions ?

Comment: @BrahmaDev yes. It's still creating new sessions (6 new session object to collection) on each page update

Comment: Then it's something else in your server code that is explicitely creating that. Look for code where you are setting any data in session.

Comment: @BrahmaDev this sessions creates for bot (I think for bot) which trying to get non-existent `/robots.txt` URL. I solved this problem by add `robots.txt` file to `public` directory of project. Also I found this: http://codingteam.net/project/tapage/browse/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js (lines 86 - 91) but that's does not work for new express.js versions.

Comment: @BrahmaDev to session saves only user's  `_id` (id of user document in collection) to `req.session.passport.user`. Example: https://pastebin.com/csqEdrDY

Comment: That seems to be because of `resave` and `saveUninitialized`. Any reasons you have set them to true ?